# Excel macro that prints individual array values to cells

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, cell

I've searched for an answer to do this but haven't found a similar situation.  I have a set of data that I want to put in array then have it print to another set of cells.

Ex.  Company A, Dept A, PriceA
     Company B, Dept B, PriceB
     Company C, Dept C, PriceC

And so on, the amount of rows will be dynamic.  I need to print each set of values and format them to various cells, but because I don't know the number of rows, I'm sure how to do this.

Comment: Could you add the code you have already?

Answer (score 0):

If your set of data begins in the same area each time and there are no empty cells between the data, you could always do something like:

```
Dim rngData As Range

Set rngData = Range("A2").End(xlDown)
```

In the example above, I assume your data starts in cell A2 and remains in column A with no spaces between data.  This is the equivalent of selecting cell A2 and holding shift and then pressing down.  It will select all of the cells.  You can then loop through each cell in your range and do whatever you need using a For ... Each loop like:

```
For Each C in rngData
'Do whatever you want for each cell
Next C
```

You can use C as you would a cell.  For example, `C.Value` will return the value of the individual cell you are on.

This is quite broad because I'm unsure exactly how your data is set up, but I hope you find this useful.